# Keyboard keys failing.

Tags: maintenance, keyboard

I have a Roland EM-1B and some keys are failing... I disassembled it, and the sensors are working correctly, even with velocity. If I press them directly with my fingers they work, also in locations known to work, ANY key that I put there work... But some keys as soon I assemble them back, they stop working again...

Does anyone have ANY clue to why this is happening?

EDIT: Seemly there are also a mechanical issue... I inserted a piece of paper between the keys and some rubber sensors, and it worked (even if in a unstable manner :/)

Answer (score 2):

Next time you open it, try to cover the rubber contacts (two per key, for velocity) with pencil. The carbon helps making contact.
Removing grease from the electronic board (where the rubber makes contact) might also help.

Answer (score 0):

How old is your keyboard?

Our church used to have a Yamaha keyboard which has been used for 5-6years. The keys started to fail one by one. We sent it to Yamaha and they fix it for us. Seems to be normal for old keyboards keys to fail and so need to be serviced.